# How to pass rows into pyspark udf

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, pyspark

I have a table with columns (id, id2, vec, vec2) where the ids are integers and the vectors are pyspark SparseVeectors.  I want to write a udf to take the dot product of vec and vec2 like so:

```
def dot_product(vec, vec2): #or do the row and I can access them later as row.vec, row.vec2?
    return vec.dot(vec2)
udf = udf(dot_product, FloatType())
dot_product = df.withColumn('dot_product', udf('vec', 'vec2'))
```

But this passes the strings 'vec' and 'vec2' as variables.  I've tried df.vec and df.vec but then it passes the whole column.  How can I do this as a row operation?  I can't use selectExpr because SQL doesn't have a dot function.  If there is an SQL method I would be open to that as well

Comment: please try  some research on udf, passing columns and vector functions. There are many answers already in stack overflow on the same topics.

Comment: @Raghu I can pass the column but then it says "Column" object is not callable.  I also realize I forgot a line in my code when I rewrote it for the question

Comment: As in the answer the columns have to be enclosed in col(). I think even than you cannot use .dot function, because column does not have that attribute.

Comment: @Raghu Yes, I've tried that as well.  I tried the answer provided below exactly as is and that doesn't work either.  I need to do a dot product so do you have any other recommendations?

Comment: You will have to implement the logic of dot product inside your UDF - something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363542/multiply-sparsevectors-element-wise

Comment: @Raghu Thank you, but I'm confused how I could use them as vectors inside the UDF to do something like that if I can't do it with the function above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217404/discussion-between-user13591820-and-raghu).

Answer (score 1):

Convert your function to a pyspark udf with

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
dot_prod_udf = F.udf(dotproduct,<returnType>)
df.select(*,dot_prod_udf(F.col('vec'),F.col('vec2')))
```

Comment: This is what I've been doing and has an error that says "Column" object is not callable.  Sorry I forgot the 'udf =...' line when I retyped this for here